# Why can't I edit this question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I was doing a little site perusal and wanted to make a few edits to [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/what-are-the-differences-between-a-child-who-was-born-normally-and-via-sectio-ca) but the edit link is disabled.  It seems to be only for this one question; I submitted edits for a [different question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5641/daughter-not-saying-mom-even-though-she-can) just after I tried to edit that one.  What's up with that, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a set of edits from another user pending approval.  Until they are reviewed and acted upon, other users without full edit permission cannot suggest further edits.

I have actually just rejected the pending edits, since they were to change the "sectio caesare" with "caesarean section", and this is something that is currently being discussed in comments on the question.  It may need a more thorough meta discussion, but I'd like to get some confirmation as to which spelling is more widely recognized, instead of just assuming that the one I'm familiar with (caesarean section) is recognized worldwide.

Comment: I see, thank you. It's been so long since I've been a novice user (I'm a veteran of EL&U), I guess I must have forgotten!